# open sets in finite metric space and discrete metric space

Tags: general-topology

How to find all the open sets in a discrete metric space? 
And I have one more question 
What are all the the open sets in a finite metric space?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132937/show-that-for-a-finite-metric-space-a-every-subset-is-open

Answer (score 1):

you know the definition of discrete metric ?
 $d(x,y)=1, x\neq y$ and $d(x, y)=0, x=y$, using this definition, 
Now $S(x, r)=\{y : d(x, y)<r\}$. You will found your answer.

Comment: i.e. every singletone set is open

Answer (score 0):

1. Show that every singleton of a metric space with the discrete metric is open.  Now as every subset is a union of singletons and a union of open sets is open, conclude that a subset is ...
2. Show that a finite metric space is discrete, that is every singleton is open.  Conclude what the open sets are.

Does every finite metric space have the discrete metric?